# What happens when I pass a concrete struct reference to a function that takes trait objects?

Tags: rust, traits, trait-objects

In the following code I have a simple trait, A, and a struct Foo that implements A...

Next, I define a function that takes a reference to a trait object. From main() I pass in a reference to a concrete Foo. This works fine and successfully calls the method in the trait.

```
trait A {
    fn do_something(&self) {
        println!("Doing something.");
    }
}

struct Foo {}
impl A for Foo {}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo {};
    make_do_something(&foo);
}

fn make_do_something(a: &dyn A) {
    a.do_something();
}
```

What is the Rust compiler doing here? Is the concrete Foo reference automatically coerced to a Trait object reference? That is, is a new trait object being created on the heap that is referring to my concrete object? I can't find a clear description of how this works in the documentation.

Comment: Yes, they're automatically coerced. This is one form of "Unsized Coercion". https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#unsized-coercions

Comment: Thanks @PitaJ. That reference helps. Maybe this question doesn't belong here but I'm not 100% certain why trait objects are unsized. That is, I figure a trait object should always contain exactly 2 pointers - a pointer to the vtable and a pointer to the concrete object. So I'm not sure why you always need &dyn Foo or Box<dyn Foo> instead of just dyn Foo.  Like why can't a dyn Foo, which is exactly 2 pointers in size live directly on the stack? I'm sure I'm missing some sublety.

Comment: A trait object `dyn Foo` is not itself a pointer, it is just a type (and one of dynamic size, etc). Only when combined with a reference or smart pointer (like `&dyn Foo` or `Box<dyn Foo>`) does it get handled as you describe. `&dyn Foo` is exactly two pointers that live on the stack.

Comment: Thanks again, @PitaJ. Your answer and the answer below from Kevin Reid has clarified this for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the concrete Foo reference automatically coerced to a Trait object reference?

Yes, the `&Foo` is [coerced](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#unsized-coercions) to `&dyn A`. The `&Foo` consists of a pointer to the data of the `Foo` (which happens to be zero bytes long in your example, but this makes no difference); the `&dyn A` consists of that pointer *and also* a pointer to the [*vtable*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/trait-object.html?highlight=vtable#trait-objects) generated from `impl A for Foo`.

> is a new trait object being created on the heap

No; a trait object demands additional data to *refer to it*, not to store it.

Compare this with the other main kind of dynamically-sized (`!Sized`) type in Rust, the slice: a `&Foo` contains a pointer to a `Foo`, and a `&[Foo]` contains that pointer *and a length*. They might be the same data pointed to (you can convert [both ways](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/fn.from_ref.html)), but the pointer is different.

We can say in general that pointing to a value of a `Sized` type requires *only* the machine pointer to the data; pointing to a value of a `!Sized` type requires additional information (called the “[metadata](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/trait.Pointee.html)”).

Every pointer to a dynamically-sized type is constructed either by a coercion, in which case the compiler inserts the necessary data that is known at compile time (vtable for a trait object, or length for a slice pointer coerced from an pointer array), or by library code which knows something about what it's constructing a pointer for (e.g. when `Vec<T>` produces a `&[T]`).